# custom kernel module not being compiled

Tags: kernel, drivers, compiling, kernel-modules

I'm playing with linux kernel, trying to write some modules. I added them in the linux sources, under /drivers/my_module/my_module.c. (I'm using kernel 4.9, on debian 9, make 4.1)

Here it is:

```
#include <linux/module.h>

__init static int my_module_init(void)
{
    pr_info("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}

__exit static void my_module_exit(void)
{
    return;
}

module_init(my_module_init);
module_exit(my_module_exit);
```

I wrote a simple Kconfig and Makefile :
Makefile:
`obj-$(CONFIG_MY_MODULE) += my_module.o`
Kconfig:

```
menu "My first module"

config MY_MODULE
        bool "My module"
        help
        The dumbest kernel module you could find on the market !

endmenu
```

I added it in the Kconfig and Makefile in /drivers :

Kconfig : `source "drivers/my_module/Kconfig"`

Makefile: `obj-$(CONFIG_MY_MODULE) += my_module/`

I thought, so far so good, however, when i add my `CONFIG_MY_MODULE=y` in the .config file of linux, it is not compiled when i run make (it does no appear in the compile output, and nothing appears in the traces when booting the kernel), and i can't understand why. My guess is that it has to do with the variable not being defined in the drivers/Makefile, but it seems that other modules uses the same strategy, and they are compiled with the kernel.

So i guess i'm missing something, but i can't really figure out what.